# How to check added crosswalk version?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, crosswalk-runtime

I am using ionic to develop hybrid app and I add crosswalk to my project via `ionic browser add crosswalk`

How can I check and verify which version of crosswalk I have added to my project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The right command is `ionic browser versions`, that shows all installed browsers and their version.

Check the [CLI source code](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/blob/4da736396f7c1a23b15716c62839ba5f411b4d8e/lib/ionic/browser.js#L96) for additional undocumented commands.

Answer (score 3):

Type **cordova plugin** in command prompt from project directory, it shows the all installed versions and plugin details.